# Sorting through MYSQL results using PHP to create category-like results

Tags: php, mysql

I've asked a [similar question][1] before, thought I got the answer, but it looks like I'm stuck...

I created a list of comics for insurance purposes.  Basically, it lists all my issues with a couple of fields, including cover, title, value and such.

Right now, I created 2 tables in MYSQL: comicstitles and comics.

In comicstitles, I have titID, titPrefix, titTitle and titType (example: 1,The,X-Men,Mini Serie).

In comics, I have comID, comTitle, comVolume, comIssue, comValue, comImgMain and such (example: 1,1,1,141,125,DaysOfFuturePast.jpg).

I am able to make a left join on the table where comID = comTitle so that I am able to output, in php, something like that:

```
The X-Men
(IMAGE)
Volume: 1
Issue: 142
Value: $125,00
```

Now, all of this is perfectly fine, but I would like to sort them by titles.

So, instead of having this:

```
Alpha Flight
(IMAGE)
Volume: 1
Issue: 1
Value: $4,00

Alpha Flight
(IMAGE)
Volume: 1
Issue: 2
Value: $3,00

The X-Men
(IMAGE)
Volume: 1
Issue: 15
Value: $800,00

The X-Men
(IMAGE)
Volume: 1
Issue: 141
Value: $125,00

The X-Men
(IMAGE)
Volume: 1
Issue: 142
Value: $125,00
```

I would like to get this:

```
Alpha Flight
(IMAGE)
Volume: 1
Issue: 1
Value: $4,00

(IMAGE)
Volume: 1
Issue: 2
Value: $3,00

The X-Men
(IMAGE)
Volume: 1
Issue: 15
Value: $800,00

(IMAGE)
Volume: 1
Issue: 141
Value: $125,00

(IMAGE)
Volume: 1
Issue: 142
Value: $125,00
```

A perfect example would be the Wordpress-like page of post by categories where you have a list of all the categories with individual post under each of the category list.

THANKS!  And happy new year to all of you :)

EDIT: 
Here's my query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comics, comicstitles WHERE comics.comTitle = comicstitles.titID ORDER BY comicstitles.titTitle ASC, comics.comIssue ASC");
```

This gives me a nice one level list, like this:

```
The X-Men, Issue 15, valued at $800
The X-Men, Issue 141, valued at $125
The X-Men, Issue 142, valued at $125
Alpha Flight, Issue 1, valued at $4
Alpha Flight, Issue 2, valued at $3
```

But I would like to have, rather:

```
The X-Men:
   Issue 15, valued at $800
   Issue 141, valued at $125
   Issue 142, valued at $125
Alpha Flight
   Issue 1, valued at $4
   Issue 2, valued at $3
```

I also need to wrap it up in nice, clean HTML, so the IDEAL thing would be to be able to do this:

```
<h2>$comicTitle</h2>
   <ul>
      <li>$comicIssue</li>
      <li>$comicIssue</li>
      <li>$comicIssue</li>
   </ul>

<h2>$comicTitle</h2>
   <ul>
      <li>$comicIssue</li>
      <li>$comicIssue</li>
      <li>$comicIssue</li>
      <li>$comicIssue</li>
      <li>$comicIssue</li>
      <li>$comicIssue</li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method to solve this kind of problem is to keep the title stored in a temp variable and to print the title only when it differs.

```
$oldtitle = NULL;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $prefix = empty($row['titPrefix']) ? '' : "{$row['titPrefix']} ";
    $title = $prefix . $row['titTitle'];
    if ($oldtitle != $title) {
       if ($oldtitle !== NULL) echo '</ul>';
       echo '<h1>'.htmlspecialchars($title).'</h1><ul>';
       $oldtitle = $title;
    }

    echo '<li><img src="'.$row['comImgMain'].'"/> '.
         ' Volume: '.$row['comVolume'] .
         ' Issue: '.$row['comIssue'] .
         ' Value: '.$row['comValue'] . '</li>';
}
if ($oldtitle !== NULL) echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks @rodrigovr!  It worked LIKE A CHARM!  And furthered my knowledge of PHP!!!  You made my day.

Comment: @Neonjack it is pleasure to help. I use this algorithm a lot with substr($title, 0, 1) to group categories by the first character.

Comment: Just awesome.  Is there a way to prevent the printing of the titPrefix  if there's none?  It creates a non-breaking space.  I thought of an if/else of some sort...

Comment: @Neonjack just added this to the answer

Comment: Once again: awesome :)

Comment: If you still have time, I'd like to push it a bit further...  Right now, it creates one big loop, but what if I want to isolate the comic issues from the title?  That way, I could have the title in a H1 tag, and the rest into a list of LI, each LI being an individual comic.

Comment: Something like: 
`H1 $title
   UL
      LI$comic
      LI$comic
      LI$comic
   /UL
H1 $title
   UL
      LI$comic
      LI$comic
      LI$comic
   /UL`

Answer (score 0):

This would need to be done with PHP and not just MySQL

First, add `ORDER BY titTitle, ...` to your query if not already ordered correctly

Second with PHP form a multidimensional array:

```
$comics_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $comics_array[$row["titTitle"]][] = array(
        "comImgMain" => $row["comImgMain"],
        "comVolume" => $row["comVolume"],
        "comIssue" => $row["comIssue"],
        ...
    );
}
```

Then when you go to print them out onto the page use PHP similar to:

```
foreach ($comics_array as $title => $comics) {
    print $title."<br />";
    foreach($comics as $comic){
        print $comic["comImgMain"]."<br />";
        print $comic["comVolume"]."<br />";
        print $comic["comIssue"]."<br />";
        print ...
        print "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hum, this seems even better, more accurate.  I'll try to implement it right away.